# Load iframe once for multiple html pages

Tags: html, iframe

I use the same iframe in multiple pages of my web application.  I want to have the iframe load once on the login screen and then when brought to the next page the same exact iframe will still be loaded and not refreshed.

Is there any way to keep a part of a webpage loaded and static when directed to the next page?  Some sort of static footer with the iframe would be great.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of submitting a form or using a link, you can `target` yet another Iframe on the page. The target will load the new page, leaving the original alone.